# Unable to save data in database in sqlite in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi I want to know how can I save data in sqlite database
and how can I compare a data from that database for loin purpose,
suppose I have a registration page and after registration I have a log in page and in that log in I want to go to next activity where I have the data of that person in a ListView 
and log in should be done via database only,
please help me out

Adapter class

```
public class DBAdapter 
{
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contacts";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
"create table contacts (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ "name text not null, email text not null, phone int not null);";
private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
this.context = ctx;
DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);//SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
    } // SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory is null by default

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        try 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
    onCreate(db);
    }
}

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a contact into the database---
public long insertContact(String name, String email, String phone)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues); // 2nd parameter -  null indicates all column values. 
}

//---deletes a particular contact---
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
{
return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; // relational operator returns true / false
}

//---retrieves all the contacts---
public Cursor getAllContacts()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,KEY_EMAIL,KEY_PHONE}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//---retrieves a particular contact---
public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
Cursor mCursor =
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL,KEY_PHONE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
null, null, null, null);
if (mCursor != null) {
mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
return mCursor;
}

//---updates a contact---
public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name, String email, String phone)
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    args.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    args.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

Main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button submit;
EditText name,email,number;
private long id;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

   // final String name1 = name.getText().toString();
   // final String email1 = email.getText().toString();
   // final String number1 = number.getText().toString();

   final  DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name1 = name.getText().toString();
            String email1 = email.getText().toString();
            String number1 = number.getText().toString();
            db.open();
            id = db.insertContact(name1,email1,number1); 

            //id = db.insertContact("Suven Consultants", "courses.suvenconsultants.com","+919892544177");
            db.close();

            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getContact(id);
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            DisplayContact(c);
            else
            //Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            db.close();

        }
    }); 


}

public void DisplayContact(Cursor c)
{
Toast.makeText(this, "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
        "Name: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
        "Email: " + c.getString(2)+ "\n" +
    "Phone: " + c.getString(3),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: i didn't see a question ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to insert the String phone number into the int-Field of the database, thats **not possible**.

Change this:

> private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
>   "create table contacts (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
>   + "name text not null, email text not null, phone int not null);";

into this:

> private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table contacts
>   (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
>   + "name text not null, email text not null, phone text not null);";

then it should work don't use int for the phone-number in the DB int is limited to a number of restrictions that could cause errors (e.g. a number that is to high to be an int-value), its much easier to cast the string from the DB later on in the application

Furthermore don't forget to **delete the old DB** on the emulator/device after you've done the changes otherwise the new create statement is not beeing executed.

Comment: That's not really true, from the SQLite doc you can read `Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.` More info: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html , but do this on purpose  is a probably cause of errors.

Comment: This means that every column, exept the primary key, can hold one of these datatypes: INTEGER, REAL, TEXT or BLOB. It does not mean that you can store data that is defined as String into a column that is defined to be integer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be doing this with a webserver that can check whether the user is registered and then verify the information. If you're just letting a user create an account and storing that data to the phone for comparison purposes just use `SharedPreferences`. It much easier than SQLite and you can store a string key value pair and read it back for compairson easily.

Comment: True, but SharedPreferences are not meant to hold a lot of data, so if you have only one Contact you can do this, but if you have a lot of them, storing into the SharedPreferences would be very bad programming style

Comment: Agreed - it just looked like this was for the log in of one user. In that case the registration page could write to SharedPreferences and be read back later. Like I said, if the point is to store and entire database of all users on the phone to check for log in, use a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `int` data type for storing phone numbers?
Integer data type have a minimum and maximum limit.
Since phone numbers are more than 6 digits, it may raise `Overflow Exception`
you must use `string` data type to store phone numbers in the database.
Try it out